# Is my 1951 "Nocaster" worth restoring?

Tags: guitar

I have a 1951 Nocaster that has been refinished and has had the pick guard replaced (among other things).  I plan on selling it and was wondering if it would be worth it to have it professionally restored before selling.

Comment: It's hard to answer without more detailed information about the condition of the guitar. What kind of shape is it in? How much of it is original?

Comment: Also, if you don't get many responses here, the [Fender Forums](http://forums.fender.com/index.php) can be very useful. Post in the [Tele forum](http://forums.fender.com/viewforum.php?f=7) (ideally with pictures) and you should get some good advice. There are a ton of vintage Fender people there with a lot of experience.

Comment: In addition, see what the going price(s) is on eBay or Craigslist.

Answer (score 3):

A look up of the guitar shows a few different prices. The highest priced seller was [a vintage seller](http://www.garysguitars.com/catalog/1951-fender-nocaster-butterscotch-blonde-fee0403) for an extremely high $57,900 for an original in mint condition. That however, does not match with what the guitars are going for on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Fender-Custom-Shop-51-Nocaster-NOS-Blonde-w-2-cases/261034572953?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131003132420%26meid%3D366344381d7e444186178a488b14e2b0%26pid%3D100005%26prg%3D20131003132420%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D121122581264&rt=nc) which is from $2,995.00 to $3,499.00. This however includes mostly non originals and remakes of that modle guitar.

Without seeing it and knowing more about yours all I can say is the least it's worth would be in the eBay range in **current condition**. I would take it to someone who can appraise the guitar for you in it's current condition. Someone who appraises  guitars should be able to tell how much it will increase in value if it is **restored** and from that you'll figure out if it's worth it to restore it or not.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @scrowler I did what I could with the information given. All the question gives it the model guitar and saying some things have been replaced. If there is more detail I can give a better answer and the best answer anyone can give right now is the last paragraph.

Comment: @scrowler There isn't nearly enough information from the OP to make a realistic estimate. Condition, number of original parts, provenance.. many factors play a part. The best answer we can really give in this situation is "it depends" until we get more info on the guitar. That being said, most of these guitars will be valued at or above $50,000 depending on condition. If it will actually sell at that price is another question entirely and that depends on the guitar, the market, and who is selling it.